# Ember: How to determine which property changed in a multi-property observer

Tags: javascript, ember.js

With something like the following how can I determine which of the three properties has changed without resorting to something tedious like printing out all the values each time, or creating three separate observers?

```
variableObserver: Ember.observer('variable.{name,value,type}', function() {

  // which property changed?

}),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using `arguments` array.

```
variableObserver : Ember.observer('variable.{name,value,type}',function(){
        this.set("changedvalue",arguments[1]);
}),
```

Added an example [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/36ba276b31d02f38803f7b4abfa90d30?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)